# iphone email form buttons doesn't work

Tags: ios, objective-c, email, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

this is how my email form looks like:

> if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {
>
> ```
>     MFMailComposeViewController *mail = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
>     mail.mailComposeDelegate = self;
>
>     [mail setSubject:@"Hello and welcome!"];
>
>     NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"email@gmail.com"];
>     [mail setToRecipients:toRecipients];
>     [mail setCcRecipients:toRecipients];
>
>     NSString *emailBody = @"Hey all!";
>     [mail setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:NO];
>
>     mail.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPageSheet;
>     [self presentViewController:mail animated:YES completion:nil];
>
>
> } else {
>     UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error!"
>                                                     message:@"E-mail is not supported on your device"
>                                                    delegate:nil
>                                           cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
>                                           otherButtonTitles:nil];
>     [alert show];
> }
> ```

Emails are sent OK but the problem is, once I hit send button the email is sent but the viewcontroller (or pop up window) does not close. And also close button doesn't work. I simply can't get out from email form.

Any ideas?

Comment: You have to implement the delegate method. Read the docs for `MFMailComposeViewController` and the delegate protocol. It covers this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be not calling

> dismissViewControllerAnimated

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES
                         completion:nil];
```

use this:

```
-(void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error{

    switch (result) {
        case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSaved:
            NSLog(@"mail saved");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSent:
            NSLog(@"mail sent");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultFailed:
            NSLog(@"mail failed");
            break;
    }
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES
                         completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Oh sure! I already have this in other app and totally forgot to add it. Thanks